# How to remove table cell fill format?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]

Like this table. How to remove the fill (not setting it to white, but to use the default pattern of the table style) in of the dark red cell. I need to remove the fill rather than choose the same color as cells in the same row, because otherwise if I add a row above the row, the fill would stay the same rather than the table's auto fill of banded rows.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click in the cell, and you'll get 2 menu bars. The context menu (list), and the toolbar. On the toolbar select `No Color` from the fill menu. The context menu will disappear at this point.

[image]

Comment: This is not working, since this will make the filling to be white. I want to keep the automatic fillings within the settings of banded rows. In other words, in my example, the filling should be light green rather than white.

Comment: @dspjm Your question states "I need to remove the fill rather than choose the same color as cells in the same row". Setting No Color is removing the fill. If that's not what you wanted, you need to edit your question to make it clear what your requirements are.

Comment: OK spikey_richie